# Notification when a data enters Firebase

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I want to know how to send notification to the user when a new data enters Firebase. As I am doing an IoT project so sensors will send a text file to the Firebase storage. And on receiving the file Firebase will send a notification to the user. How should I do it?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 2):

You can create firebase cloud functions, which are triggered when data changes in firebase database, to send firebase cloud message.

Here is a complete example which shows how to use cloud functions to handle realtime database events.

http://www.zoftino.com/android-firebase-cloud-functions-realtime-database-trigger-example